# Factorization of $x^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Fermat numbers are defined by $F_n=2^n+1$. The problem asks to find that in order to $F_n$ to be a prime, $n=2^m$. When $n$ is odd we can find the factorization:

$$
x^n+1=(x+1)(1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots+x^{n-1}),
$$

and thus $2^n+1$ is composite. How do you prove that if n is even (but not a power of two), one can factorize the polynomial? How do you prove that when $n=2^m$ the polynomial cannot be factorized?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers

Comment: Note that the statement you want to prove is "if $F_{n}$ is a prime, then $n = 2^{m}$", and not the converse (we actually only know of five Fermat primes).

Comment: We can use the same factorization if $n=2^k\cdot q$ where $q$ is odd, namely $2^n+1 \ = \ \big(2^{(2^k)}\big)^q +1$,
so use $x=2^{(2^k)}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ has an odd divisor $d$, then $2^{m/d}+1$ divides $2^m+1$.

Comment: Yes, this is easy to show. My question is how do you prove that $x^{2^n}+1$ has no factorization (at least it cannot be factorized over the real).